# Create custom Index via Metadata API now possible?

Tags: metadata-api, custom-index

While doing prodsync today I stumbled upon a folder named as customIndex. Funnily enough it had all custom indexes that we had asked SF to create for us. Once downloaded, I tried to save this in my Sandbox and it really created a custom index on DateTime column.

I was always assuming that we cant create custom indexes and need to reach out to SF support for this.

> Salesforce supports custom indexes to speed up queries, and you can
> create custom indexes by contacting Salesforce Customer Support.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_indexes.htm
[image]

[image]

Is this some new feature or undocumented behavior leak?

Comment: Can you share the path where you found custom index folder?

Comment: I noticed that customIndex is listed in [Metadata Coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/55) . I'll check with the concerned team and get back with more inputs. Thank you

Comment: Hello @Pranay - Have you got any confirmation or anything?

Comment: @JefersonChaves no have not received any conf from SF..

Comment: @Swetha any updates?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I've followed up again for inputs internally. Can you share the path where you found custom index folder? Though I've included customIndex in my manifest's package.xml, I couldn't find customIndex in my dev org. Thanks

Comment: @Swetha use Org Browser and pulll it from over there.. You need to have custom index in your orgs.  I have updated location of it in org browser.

Answer (score 4):

The development to support of custom index in packages, led to custom index being exposed as a metadata. The Salesforce team has filed a documentation bug numbered #W-11868878 (ETA- Spring'23 Safe Harbor) to add that

> Custom Index metadata was made available to support custom index in packaging. Customers are advised not to create custom indexes on their own, without having a full understanding of all the performance implications. Customers can create custom indexes by contacting Salesforce Customer Support as detailed in [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_indexes.htm).

Also, see the related Custom Index [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_custom_index) that went live recently(Oct'22).

Comment: Thanks Swetha, that helps a lot to clarify this subject.